# Finding the largest number, its frequency, stopping at 0

Tags: c

So I have to write a program that reads numbers, finds the largest number, and tells the user how frequently it appears. The program also needs to stop once it reads 0, but I'm having trouble with that.

So far if I input it prints max as 0 every time. The frequency also gets screwed up sometimes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <cstdlib>

int main()
{
int max, count, a;

count =1;
printf("Enter numbers:");
scanf("%d", max);

do 
{
scanf("%d",&a);

if(max<a)
 {
    max=a;
    count=1;
    }
else if (max=a)
{
    count++;
    }
else count+=0;
}


while(a!=0);

printf ("The largest number is %d, and it occurs %d times \n", max, count);

/* system("pause"); */
printf("Press enter to continue...\n");
fflush(stdin);
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: The answers below address the real issues in your code, but... `else count+=0;`? What is it you hope to achieve here?

Comment: @mah The true programmer is putting two glasses near his bed at night. A glass with water, in case he will be thirsty, and an empty one, in case he won't.

Comment: `#include <cstdlib>` suggests you are using a C++ compiler.  Recommend to use a C compiler for C source code.

Answer (score 2):

I see three errors as of now,

1. While asking for user input

   ```
   scanf("%d", max);
   ```

   is wrong. `scanf()` expects a pointer type augment for the supplied format specifier. Change that to

   ```
   scanf("%d", &max);
   ```
2. Then, `else if (max=a)` is also erroneous. `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison.
3. `fflush(stdin);` is  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You're not supposed to use `fflush()` on input streams.

Answer (score 1):

`else if (max=a)` is erroneous. The comparison operator is `==` not `=`, which is assignment.